# Python GtkBuilder can't import Box widget from Glade 3.14

Tags: python, glade, gtk3

In my layout, I use a ton of box layouts. In most tutorials I looked, people would use `HBox` and `VBox`'s. I didn't think that a `Box` would be that much different.

The GtkBuilder chokes miserably anytime I have a `Box` layout in the Glade file, giving me the following error message:

`Gtk:ERROR:/build/buildd/gtk+3.0-3.6.0/./gtk/gtknotebook.c:1235:gtk_notebook_buildable_add_child: assertion failed: (page != NULL)`

I've looked this up, and the best response they had was to revert back to Glade 3.8. I don't want to do that because Glade 3.8 was designed for GTK+ 2, and I want to develop for GTK+ 3 (I'm really liking the Gnome shell interface). Thus, I'm trying to stick with 3.14.

Is there another version of `GtkBuilder` that supports the new `Box` layout? It just seems odd that the Glade developers would break their support like that without updating the corresponding `GtkBuilder` object.

Here's the Python code that creates the interface:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindow(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file('main-window.glade')

        self.window = self.builder.get_object('mainWindow')

        self.builder.connect_signals(self)
```

Any help or advise is much appreciated!

Comment: What does make you think the problem is with GtkBox? The error says a notebook can't add a child.  Do you have a very small test case with glade?  Say, a GtkWindow, a GtkNotebook, a GtkBox inside of a page, and a GtkLabel inside the GtkBox.

Comment: I should read error messages better... Realized that my GtkNotebook didn't have anything in some of its pages. That would explain why it complained about `assertion failed: (page != NULL)`. Just to be thorough, I did some tests with the `Box` layout, including leaving some spaces empty, and it works just fine. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You should add it as an answer and accept it.  Other people might see benefit on that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to gpoo for helping me in figuring this out:

**Make sure to read your error messages!** I had a `GtkNotebook` with blank pages, which made the `GtkBuilder` complain. So no blank pages.

Also, `GtkBox` works just fine in all its permutations (at least the Python interface, anyway).

Comment: Ah, I'm glad you found the solution; I was source-diving into GTK+ and still didn't realize that the *blank* page in the interface designer was the problem. The gtknotebook.c code complains about a *missing* page. The Glade (3.6.7 here) UI also isn't very obvious here - it shows empty pages as blank, but existing.

Comment: Just had the same problem with the notebook. And I somewhat regret having passed to Glade 3.18... It's sooo slow. I've no idea why, but even on a 3.6GHz machine it takes more than a second to refresh the display. I hope I won't regret having converted to gtk3...